# Generic method to replace two

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to make below methods generic, this method makes a search using a search service, and all possible URL's are in a  dictionary.

```
public XDocument DoSearchForTypeA()
{
    return searchService.Search(dictionary["optiona"]);
}

public XDocument DoSearchForTypeB()
{
    return searchService.Search(dictionary["optionb"]);
}
```

I was thinking on doing something like this:

```
public XDocument DoSearch<T>()
{
    if(typeof(T)==typeof(MyTypeA))
    {
        return searchService.Search(dictionary["optiona"]);
    }
    return searchService.Search(dictionary["optionb"]);
}
```

I see my solution really awful. Mainly cause i dont like the switches or ifs parsing each type. It makes the code not so flexible for scale it.

I would like to have a more elegant solution, but I have the feeling that this is not the best example for using generic methods. Could you give me some advices on this reflection?

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, I would keep the two methods. What happens if you call it with `DoSearch<string>`? That's legal code as far as the compiler is concerned but will end up searching the wrong dictionary (most likely). Is that what you want? *Why* do you feel the need to combine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary is one of the options:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, String> s_Search = new Dictionary<Type, String>()
{
    {typeof(MyTypeA), "optiona"},
    {typeof(MyTypeB), "optionb"}
}

...

public XDocument DoSearch<T>()
{ 
    return searchService.Search(dictionary[s_Search(typeof(T))]);
}
```